# Flight time between Taipei - Vienna vs Vienna - Taipei

Tags: time

I recently took a flight between Vienna (Austria) - Taipei (Taiwan) and then back Taipei - Vienna.

The interesting thing that I don't understand is why it takes longer to fly TPE - VIE than VIE - TPE?

Vienna - Taipei - 11h40mins:
[Vienna-Taipei](https://www.prokerala.com/travel/flight-time/from-vienna/to-taipei/)

Taipei - Vienna - 13h 40mins (two hours longer):
[Taipei-Vienna](https://www.prokerala.com/travel/flight-time/from-taipei/to-vienna/)

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Does this answer your question? [Why do flight times differ between traveling East versus traveling West?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/why-do-flight-times-differ-between-traveling-east-versus-traveling-west)

Comment: I see now that the pilot must have observed the wind prediction before flight - but what is interesting is the fact that flight path was also longer - he first flew at least 1000 km to the nord - and then to the west. What would happen if the pilot took shortest path to Vienna? How long would the flight be? I understand we would face then headwinds - obviously it's still better to make extra 1000 km than to face headwind?

Comment: Two Words: WINDS ALOFT

Comment: winds aloft and temporary airspace closures. Say you're not allowed to fly over a specific country for the return flight for some reason, so you need a detour.

Comment: @FrenkyB, we are talking about winds that can reach quarter of the speed of the aircraft itself. A 1000 km is just a bit over eighths of the distance. Well worth it. Also, the shortest route from Taipei to Vienna starts north-west. The eastbound flight is the one that usually makes huge detour (and is still faster with the 100 knot tailwind).